# Stormcrawler and regex when parsing rules in the default-regex-filters.txt?

Tags: regex, stormcrawler

If I need to crawl just ONE host in a domain while still crawling the rest of our sites, what's the regex to put in the default-regex-filters.txt to accomplish that?

I am trying to block all hosts at https://*.bar.com while allowing ONLY https://foo.bar.com

Can I do a generalized `-^https?://.*\.bar\.com.*` rule followed by a specific rule allowing the one host `+^https?://foo\.bar\.com.*`  Will that work?

I tried to do a complicated `-^https?://([a-eg-zA-EG-Z0-9]` type of thing to block everything but `foo` but it seems much simpler to just negate everything and add back the one I actually want...

Comment: *Will that work?* Have you tried it?

Comment: My first attempt with the complicated regex didn't work. the crawler siezed up and didn't crawl anything. My second attempt didn't actually remove the other hosts so I had to delete 53,000+ spurious urls. {headdesk} I am attempting the above now.

Comment: I more curious if a generalized negative rule `-`, followed by a more specific positive rule `+` is the proper way to do these sorts of things.

Comment: Well, `^https?://.*\.bar\.com(?:/.*)?$` looks to only match  `some-string.bar.com` hosts. See https://regex101.com/r/lGTRyK/1

Comment: ...and that's exactly what I'm looking for. I'm curious if the Stormcrawler parsing of the default-regex-filters.txt simply stops checking the file if it finds a match on the `*.bar.com` line or if it will continue on and see the exception for `foo.bar.com` and allow that...

Comment: I suspect - after checking some existing answers on SO - that the most specific rules must come first (above) more generic rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most specific rules should come first indeed, see code

https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/399cdac2125c39ef9be26586a2ca2609f92b0988/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/filtering/regex/RegexURLFilterBase.java#L156

The fastURLFilter https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/URLFilters follows the same logic but could be simpler to organize.

Comment: OK, I will look into the FastURLFilter, but for the default-regex-filters.txt this doesn't seem to work. did I do something wrong? I put this `+^https://www\.foo\.com/tour/site`
followed by `-^https://www\.foo\.com/.*` on the next line. It seems to not be crawling that page at all. It says `FETCHED` for status, but it does that for every page it ignores via the regex. thoughts?

Comment: update: I even tried to incorporate a 'not' into the -^ regex to try to ignore everything BUT that one url: `-^https:\/\/www\.foo\.com\/((?!tour\/site)).*` but that does not appear to work either.

Comment: FETCHED means, well, that is has been fetched successfully. You need to delete the pages from the status index first - the filter is applied to newly discovered URLs, if the URLs have already been put in the status, they won't get deleted